# Time efficiency of running a loop over two comparisons, versus looping twice over one comparison each

Tags: performance, time-complexity

The title may seem confusing, but what I mean, I will show in code:

```
for x in array {
    if (x == 6)
       print("match")
    if (x == 8)
       print("match")
}
```

vs

```
for x in array {
    if (x == 6)
       print("match")
}
for x in array {
    if (x == 6)
       print("match")
}
```

I would assume they are both O(2n) or O(n), but I am not positive. If looping requires more computational power than comparison for some reason, then I would be incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime of each of these loops is O(n), since you're visiting each of the n elements a constant number of times (one time in the first case, two times in the second case) and doing at most a constant amount of work on each element.

Big-O notation measures the asymptotic runtime of a piece of code, though, so saying that both pieces of code run in time O(n) doesn't mean that they take the same amount of time to complete. You'd have to measure this on your specific system with your specific setup to see which is faster. I suspect the first version will be faster, though, since it only makes one pass through the list.

That being said, I would be cautious about trying to optimize code like this. Aim for clarity first, and if you find that this is a performance bottleneck, then consider revising it. Chances are that if this is slowing down your entire program, switching to another representation of the data, such as storing everything in a hash table or balanced BST, will be faster because the cost of checking whether an element is there is expected O(1) or O(log n), respectively, for those container types.

Comment: Thanks. You make a very good point. I am constantly trying to optimize my code or play code golf, but in the end, I bet it is not very easily readable by others. I guess my main question, and I get this depends on the system, is that moving one over in an array/ a single iteration in a loop, takes more time than just a simple comparison (in most cases/machines, I'd assume). Thanks!